# What is a word/phrase to describe someone who thinks someone else is perfect?

Tags: adjectives

What is a word/phrase to describe someone who thinks someone else is perfect?  For instance, if parents think that their child can do no wrong, then they are . . .? (Not necessarily biased or partial, because it is not in comparison to anyone else)

Comment: Your question's title and its body do not match in their current state, in regards to a single question. Change one, or the other.

Comment: That person is wearing [**rose-colored glasses**](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/311187/63734)

Comment: They are fools.

Comment: "Naive" would suffice if you want to be more tactful about the lack of wisdom.

Answer (score 13):

How about the really common [**admiring**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/admire)?

> to regard with wonder, pleasure, or approval.

Also, consider [**idolizing**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/idolize?s=t)

> to regard with blind adoration, devotion, etc.

**Worshiping** is relevant, but I'm not 100% sure if it fits your exact request.

And [**glorifying**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/glorify?s=t)

> to honor with praise, admiration, or worship

Comment: I think idolizing is just perfect for this application.  It gives just the right sense of the behavior being out of balance (where adoring seems like something any parent might naturally do) and doting seems to indicate that the child is still very young.  Idolizing goes right on into adulthood!

Answer (score 11):

At the risk of being a bit too obvious, there is always **Awestruck**, which, quite literally means

> Filled with Awe

It's not necessarily an appropriate term to use for parents who think their child can do no wrong - but then, I wouldn't describe that as Awe.

Now a child who thinks *their parent* can do no wrong- that's a strong use of both 'awe' and 'awestruck'.

Comment: I upvoted this one before the question changed to take "awe" out.  Changing the question necessarily changes the answer, too.  I can't withdraw my vote without the answer changing, but it ought to let me do that because the question changed too, dammit.

Comment: @Monty it ought to be noted that the question was rewritten by someone other than the original asker, in a matter that, as you noted, radically changes the question. While the editors interpretation of the original intent is **a** valid interpretation, it is far from the **only** valid interpretation. I'm not interested in starting a rollback war, but I'm also not going to rewrite or delete this answer to reflect a revision that I feel has dubious value.

Answer (score 8):

**Doting** would be a good word here.

> showing a lot of love for somebody, often ignoring their faults

Comment: *Doting* is good, but it is almost always used only in the specific sense of describing the attitude of an indulgent parent or relative to a child (admittedly the specific example the OP gave)

Comment: I would argue that although that is its most common usage, it doesn't have to be limited to that, but it's a point to keep in mind nonetheless.

Comment: It probably doesn't *have* to be limited to that, but personally it would seem weird to me if I heard it used in any other context.

Comment: Dotage is giving things to someone that they want, not thinking that they are flawless. Nursing, in a sense.

Comment: @TheNate Dotage is a noun, meaning "​old ​age, ​especially with some ​loss of ​mental ​ability" (Cambridge dictionary). It's nothing to do with giving things to someone that they want, and it doesn't mean the same thing as doting. Furthermore, the word "dote" literally means "be extremely and uncritically fond of." or some variation of that in most dictionaries, meaning it is 100% what the OP asked for.

Comment: The original word means foolish or stupid and the need to tend them seems to have grown out of that. So "want" was a poor choice, but "need" is too strong, anymore.
 "Most dictionaries" told you the terms weren't related, did they?

Comment: They did not, that was my opinion. The only thing I was referencing a dictionary for was the definition of dote, but I thank you for the alternative interpretation.

Comment: I will admit that I had not realized that the definition accepted as common use had drifted quite so far. Hazards of reading classics, I suppose.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest **Adoring**

from ***adore***: to regard with the utmost esteem, love, and respect; honor. ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/adore))

Comment: I can be in awe of someone I hate.  I can respect and admire someone's ability while still considering them to be the spawn of Satan.  On the flip side of that, I can adore someone while still recognizing that they are far from perfect or deeply flawed.

Answer (score 5):

Consider **enthralled**.

> *enthrall*
>
> verb (enthralls, enthralling, enthralled) [ with obj. ]
>
> capture the fascinated attention of: she had been so enthralled by the
>     adventure that she had hardly noticed the cold.

Comment: I've never heard _enthralled_ used with a person. Maybe her actions, but never a person.

Comment: Given that *thrall* historically meant “a captive person” or “servant,” I think it's appropriate to use with a person as the object.

Answer (score 4):

How about *adulation*?

> excessive or slavish admiration or flattery

source: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adulation

Comment: Some rando down-voting this? HAH! This word is just as good as most.

Answer (score 3):

Consider, **put on a pedestal**

put on a pedestal - to believe that someone is perfect

Answer (score 2):

Consider [enchanted](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=define:+enchanted):

> **fill (someone) with great delight; charm.**
>
> "Isabel was enchanted with the idea"
>
> *synonyms*:   captivate, charm, delight, enrapture, entrance, enthrall, beguile, bewitch, spellbind, fascinate, hypnotize, mesmerize, rivet, grip, transfix

Answer (score 2):

Consider,

***think the world of***

> *Inf.* Adore or admire greatly; *He thinks the world of his children.* [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/think%20the%20world%20of)

***starry-eyed***

> Unrealistically or naively optimistic. [FOD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Starry-eyed)
>
> *If parents think that their child can do no wrong, then they are starry-eyed.*

Answer (score 1):

I think Idolizing is probably the best fit, but it seems that you're looking to place an adjective/title on the people that perform this behavior then it would be more appropriate to say that they are **idolizers**.  Here are a couple other options in the same neighborhood:

**Venerator** - A person that regards or treats with reverence; revere.

**Fanatics** - could also be another consideration as that has an implied sense of blindness to negative qualities

Answer (score 1):

[**Idealizer**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/idealize?q=idealizer#idealize__17) - someone who tends to [idealize/idealise](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/idealize):

> Regard or represent as perfect or better than in reality

Example sentence:

> *Orwell was indeed unsociable, anti-feminist and homophobic, but only ambiguously anti-Semitic, and by no means such a dewy-eyed idealiser of the plebs as some have imagined.*

(def and example from ODO).

It doesn't work that well if you want an adjective, but you could use a participle:

> *A cognitive theory perspective emphasizes that **idealizing parents** may cause the child to develop an overactive view of the self that includes inflated beliefs of personal uniqueness and self-importance. In this approach to child rearing, the parents may systematically deny or distort negative feedback to their child.*

from: [Narcissism in the Workplace: Research, Opinion and Practice](https://books.google.rs/books?id=toLtfZhebf0C&pg=PA55&dq=%22idealizing+parents%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22idealizing%20parents%22&f=false) by Andrew J. DuBrin, Edward Elgar Publishing, 2012

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat figurative phrase could be **being the thrall of someone**, or **in thrall of someone**, especially if the admiration causes a sense of unthinking loyalty.

Answer (score 0):

**[Infatuated](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/infatuated)**

> possessed by a foolish or extravagant passion, esp for another person

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for the idiom **rose-colored glasses**

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rose-colored_glasses#English

> 2. (idiomatic) An optimistic perception of something; a positive opinion; seeing something in a positive way, often thinking of it as better than it actually is.

---

Guy1: Jeez, that child is ransacking the bounce-house!

Guy2: Try telling that to the parent wearing the **rose-colored glasses**.

Guy1: Yeah, that parent never sees any fault in their child.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is from the Japanese:

> To him, even her farts smell sweet

Comment: Why do you suspect a Japanese origin?